# How to convert string "str1:1,str2:2,str33:33... " to array on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

Please, tell me, how I can convert string `"str1:1,str2:2,str33:33... "` to this array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [mystr] => str1
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [mystr] => str33
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mystr] => str2
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you show us your so far tried code ?

Comment: This is easily achieved using `explode`.

Answer (score 2):

Go with the `foreach` way....

#### Explanation :

Explode the elements using the comma operator and pass them as the arguments for your `foreach` construct. Now `explode()` the argument using `:` as the delimiter and then add the first exploded element as the **value**, the second exploded element as the **key**.

```
foreach(explode(',',$str) as $v)
{
    $v = explode(':',$v);
    $newarr[$v[1]]['mystr']=$v[0];
}
print_r($newarr);
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/136783)

---

The `array_map()` way...

```
<?php
$newarr = array();
array_map(function ($v) use(&$newarr){ $v = explode(':',$v);$newarr[$v[1]]['mystr']=$v[0]; },explode(',','str1:1,str2:2,str33:33'));
print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "str1:1,str2:2,str33:33";
$array  =   explode(",",$str);
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $value  =   explode(":",$value);
    $newarray[$value[1]]['mystr']   =   $value[0];
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP **[`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode)** function breaks a string into an array use explode for break your string **`comma (,)`** and foreach iteration to again explode **`colon (:)`** sign.

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/P0FwOo)**</kbd>

```
<?php   
    $str = "str1:1,str2:2,str33:33";

    foreach(explode(',',$str) as $s){
        $s = explode(':',$s);
        $array[$s[1]]['mystr']=$s[0];
    }
    print_r($array);

?>
```

#### Result

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [mystr] => str1 ) [2] => Array ( [mystr] => str2 ) [33] => Array ( [mystr] => str33 ) )
```

Comment: How is yours different from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23076951/1003917) that was answered 9 mins ago ? :)

Comment: Is this anything wrong if multiple user try to solve and not any possibility to solve same solution ?

Comment: Nope nothing wrong in helping , but you already know that your answer looks exactly the ditto of the above , so why post it ? Just asking.

Comment: here i m trying to solving question but sometime i'm reach to 99% solution and someone put answer. so at that moment i feel badly but think that i m but at least i put my afforded answer if someone check and give a vote. I'm not expectation to get vote without my effort hope you got me.+1 i give you.